# How can I get list of postgres clusters in windows

Tags: postgresql

I'm trying to get a list of my postgreSQL clusters on windows.  In linux it seems you can run pg_lsclusters, but it seems to not be available on windows.  Does anyone have any suggestions?

I'm running postgreSQL 11.

Comment: That is hard to answer in general, because there is no central repository that stores such information. If all your PostgreSQL clusters are managed as Windows services, you could list all services with "postgres" in their name.

Comment: OK... thanks.  I'm trying to follow a tutorial on replication but they're working in linux.  sounds like I can likely skip that part.  I will post another question specific to the issue that I'm having.